# IHttpModule behaves differently on different servers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express, ihttpmodule

I'm developing an application and I'm debugging the code with Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2010 and the code behaves differently with the two programs.

In VS 2010, after the code behind has been executed and the page has been built, the execution ends. In VS 2013, after the page has been built, it gets fired another call to the method context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) in IHttpModule, which I have implemented.

First problem is: why is there this additional call?

Second problem: the IHttpModule gets the path through GetVirtualPath(), and then makes a redirection with it. The problem is: why is the path got the path of the starting page and not the page it is currently in?

Comment: Can you post the 1st and 2nd call URL?

Comment: 1. http://localhost:50166/Account/Register_Step0.aspx (last correct call) 2. http://localhost:50166/__browserLink/requestData/53a4a5464d2b4887a5b5358512251198 (additional call) 3. http://localhost:50166/Account/LogIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f__browserLink%2frequestData%2f2528b242a00646a98acae54d3c4c9cad (additional call, from the login page!!)

Comment: Perhaps it's this function: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link but i have no idea, sry :/

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If you write it as answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's this function: [Using Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)
but i have no idea, sry :/