# Is it possible to persist session data on IIS Express cross different web projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session, iis

We have an existing ASP.NET Web Forms application which contains many different Visual Studio web projects. All web projects were configured to run under same localhost root path (e.g. http://localhost:12345/main/projectspecificname). We use state server to keep the session data and cookieless is set to false.

This approach worked OK when using VS2012 and ASP.NET Development Server. However when we tried to run same application from VS2015 + IIS Express we found it cannot keep session data when redirects happen between different web projects. For example, when calls Response.Redirect("**project2/index.aspx**") from **project1/login.aspx**, from Page_Load event in **project2/index.aspx** I see the session variable lost all the data carried on it(i.e. Session.Count == 0). Same debug procedure against ASP.NET Development Server returns a count greater than 0. Again, for IIS Express, all different projects were configured to use project URL like http://localhost:12345/main/projectspecificname.

I have searched a bit and found this SO post [IIS Express doesn't keep session data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995371/iis-express-doesnt-keep-session-data) which mentioned a solution as to disable Browser Link in VS, but that doesn't work for my case. I am just wondering whether we missed some settings or this approach won't work for IIS Express. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the session cookie being presented by the browser to both sites?

Comment: @JohnWu There's only one site. In the http request I see same session id posted to both pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. Looks like IIS Express treated these projects as different web applications so session initialized every time it tried to connect to another project.

By default Visual Studio creates an `<application>` node holding information like virtual path, application pool and physical path under `<site>` section in applicationhost.config for each web project. Remove `<application>` nodes for the web projects you don't want to run as a separate web application will make them run under same web site as per their physical path indicate.Therefore, session data can be correctly maintained between pages from different projects as they are considered in the same application now.